# Reselect dropdownlist after submit/error . validation

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm sorry but my brain is totally fogging up on this one.
I want to have my dropdownlist 'editprojectSelect' to be selected if there is an error with validation. P.S. in the picture i posted u can see i specifically entered a string 'test' where there should be an integer.

```
     <div id="project-wijzigen" class="form">
        <h2> Wijzig een project </h2>       

        <select id="editprojectSelect" name="editprojectSelect" onchange="getDetails()">
        <option value="">-</option>
        </select>
        <?php echo '<input type="hidden" id="hidden-input" value="'.$_POST['editProjectSelect'].'">';?>
        <div id="editProject">
            <?php echo form_open('c_admin/wijzigProject');?>
                <h2 id="hoofding"></h2>
                <div><label> Project titel: </label> <input type="text" id="pt" name="titel" required value="<?php echo set_value('projecttitel'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> Startdatum: </label> <input type="text" id="sd" name="start" required value="<?php echo set_value('startdatum'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> Einddatum: </label> <input type="text" id="ed" name="eind" required value="<?php echo set_value('einddatum'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> In samenwerking met: </label> <input type="text" id="samen" name="samen" required value="<?php echo set_value('ism'); ?>"/></div>
                <div><label> Omschrijving: </label> <textarea id="omschr" name="text" required value="<?php echo set_value('text'); ?>"></textarea></div>
                <input type="hidden" id="hiddenID" name="hiddenID" />

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Wijzig project"/>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>

     <?php  

// --------------------------- Error checking/display           
            if(isset($projectWijzigenError)) // check of de variabele wel een waarde heeft (als je die zomaar oproept en hij moest leeg of NULL zijn dan krijg je een error op je pagina)
                {
                if ($projectWijzigenError=='true') // ALS er een error is, dan opent de form terug en worden errors weergegeven
                {
?>
                    <script>
                    $("#editProjectSelect").val($('#hidden-input').val());
                    $('#project-wijzigen').show();
                    $(this).toggleClass('close');
                    </script>

<?php 
                echo validation_errors('<p class="error">'); 
                }  
                }
// -------------------------- End error checking/displaying             
?>

    </div>


---------------
        $(document).ready(function()
        {           
            $(function()
            { 
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url:"<?php echo site_url("c_admin/ajaxTitels");?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(msg)
                    {                           
                        var jsonMsg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                        var count = Object.keys(jsonMsg).length;
                        for(var x = 0; x < count; x++)
                        {   
                            $("#projectSelect").append($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].ProjectID).html(jsonMsg[x].Projecttitel)); 
                            $("#delprojectSelect").append($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].ProjectID).html(jsonMsg[x].Projecttitel));
                            $("#editprojectSelect").append($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].ProjectID).html(jsonMsg[x].Projecttitel));             
                        }
                    }
                });       
            });     
        })
        function getDetails()
        {   
            //$("#editProject").empty();
            document.getElementById('editProject').style.display = "none";
            $(".error").empty();
            var sel = document.getElementById('editprojectSelect');
            var opt = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
            var p = opt.value;

            if(p != "")
            {
                document.getElementById('editProject').style.display = "block";
                //$("#editProject").append($("<label></label><br />").html("test"));
                $.ajax(
                {
                url:"<?php echo site_url("c_admin/ajaxProject");?>",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {project: p},
                success: function(msg)
                    {                       
                        var jsonMsg = $.parseJSON(msg);

                        $('#hoofding').html(jsonMsg.Projecttitel);
                        document.getElementById("pt").value = jsonMsg.Projecttitel;
                        document.getElementById("sd").value = jsonMsg.Startdatum;
                        document.getElementById("ed").value = jsonMsg.Einddatum;
                        document.getElementById("samen").value = jsonMsg.ISM;
                        document.getElementById("omschr").value = jsonMsg.Projecttekst;
                        document.getElementById("hiddenID").value = jsonMsg.ProjectID;

                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{           
    $(function()
    { 
        $.ajax(
        {
            url:"<?php echo site_url("c_admin/ajaxTitels");?>",
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(msg)
            {                           
                var jsonMsg = $.parseJSON(msg);
                var count = Object.keys(jsonMsg).length;
                for(var x = 0; x < count; x++)
                {   
                    $("#projectSelect").append($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].ProjectID).html(jsonMsg[x].Projecttitel)); 
                    $("#delprojectSelect").append($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].ProjectID).html(jsonMsg[x].Projecttitel));
                    $("#editprojectSelect").append($("<option></option>").val(jsonMsg[x].ProjectID).html(jsonMsg[x].Projecttitel));             
                }
            }
        });       
    });
    if(isset($projectWijzigenError) AND ($projectWijzigenError == true)){
        var projectId = '<?php echo set_value('editProjectSelect'); ?>';
        //set the select field
        $("#editProjectSelect").val(projectId);
        //call the getDetails function to populate your fields
        getDetails();    
    }
```

Your `<select>` field is not inside the `<form>` element. So when you submit the form, the field is not submitted and PHP/codeigniter does not know your old value.

What you can do is, put the select field inside the form.
Once your form is submitted and if there are validation errors, do the following:

1. Get the value of the `editprojectSelect`, and in `$(document).ready` part of jquery after the ajax call, set the value of the `select` to what you got from your form.
2. After that, call the `getDetails()` function.

Comment: Had to change ur code to 
  `if((typeof($projectWijzigenError) != "undefined" && $projectWijzigenError == true)){
        var projectId = '<?php echo set_value('editProjectSelect'); ?>';
        //set the select field
        $("#editProjectSelect").val(projectId);
        //call the getDetails function to populate fields
        getDetails();    
    }
})` 

Right now im figuring out why i cant put the select in the form.. somehow it wont display if i put it there :s